# Add a static page that links to homepage

Tags: pages, homepage, customization

My home page is a dynamic page and on my navbar I have  different static pages I want to add one to link to the homepage as if I clicked the logo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a link to the homepage in your navbar, you can use the following function to add a link to the home page in `wp_page_menu_args`

```
function wpse01_home_link( $args ) {
   if ( 'main-menu' === $args -> theme_location){
       if (! isset( $args['show_home'] ) )
          $args['show_home'] = _x( 'Home', 'homepage' );
   }
   return $args;
}

add_filter( 'wp_page_menu_args', 'wpse01_home_link' );
```

You can just rename `Home` to suite your needs

Comment: It works just fine but it adds the link on a separated menu what ruins the navbar

Comment: Check update, add condition to only add home to primary menu

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: No, not really!  sorry what do you mean by check update ? update the page under the pages menu or what ?

Comment: I have updated/changed the code in my answer, that is what I meant :) see if that helps

Comment: It didn't to register my menus I used 
`function register_menus() {
 register_nav_menus(array(
  'main-menu' => 'header menu',
  'category-menu' => 'Category Menu',
  'footer-menu' => 'footer Menu'
 ));
}
add_action('init', 'register_menus');`

Comment: Change `'primary'` to `'main-menu'` in my code. I have already updated the code in my answer. Please check

Comment: it doesn't show up at all, I think if we kept the original code with the late modification it would work

Comment: I have updated my code again. Please see if that solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can add "Custom" links to WordPress menus. There, just enter the URL to your website with the title you want.

[image: Custom links]

Comment: even though I had to redesign the CSS it worked

Comment: That's good to hear. If the answer works for you, please mark it as "Accepted".